# Why are square roots of lines in the complex plane hyperbolas?

Tags: complex-numbers, soft-question, conic-sections

I was recently asked in a homework problem to sketch the image of
the half plane $\Re(z) \ge 1$ under the square root map (defined in such a way as to take 1 to itself and be continuous).

It turns out that the square root of the line $1 + it$ (for $t \in \mathbb{R}$) is the the right branch of the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ (I've included the way I arrived at this answer below). Using this it is clear that the image of any other line (or ray, if we wish to remain in this half-plane) under the map is a rotated hyperbola.

I was wondering whether there is some way to understand 'why' these hyperbolas appear. For example, in the case of the map $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ it is easy to verify that lines that don't cross the origin become circles touching the origin, and I can rationalize this by observing that inversion corresponds to a rotation of the Riemann sphere.

However, as far as I am aware, the square root map can't even be defined properly on the Riemann sphere. Moreover, the inverse image of a hyperbola under the stereographic projection seems to be half of a lemniscate-like figure that I can't even recognize, much less visualise as the square root of a circle (on the Riemann sphere).

Which brings me to the question: is there some `natural way' to see that this is a hyperbola?

---

**Computing the square root** (@Nate gives a quicker way below)

We can parametrize the vertical line $1 + it$ as
$$\sec \theta e^{i \theta} \text{ for } -\frac{\pi}{2} < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}.$$
Taking the square root and setting $\phi := \frac{\theta}{2}$
the resulting curve is
$$\sqrt{\sec{2\phi}} e^{i \phi} \text{ for } |\phi| < \frac{\pi}{4}$$
which is, in Cartesian coordinates,
\begin{align*}
 x &= \sqrt{\sec 2 \phi} \cos \phi \\
 y &= \sqrt{\sec 2 \phi} \sin \phi \\
\end{align*}
But (squaring, subtracting, and using the addition formula for cosines) this is precisely the right branch of the hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$.

---

**Caveat**

Please don't answer with a method of showing that the square root of a line is a hyperbola; if there are more elegant ways of deriving this I'd be happy to hear of them, but I'm quite satisfied with my method and am more curious about the other things I've mentioned.

---

***Addendum***:
As @Andrew D. Hwang points out below, it takes some work to establish a correspondence between clines in the plane and circles on the Riemann sphere, something (my words) I've conveniently glossed over. My reason for doing this was that *once this correspondence has been established*, the computation required to show that inversion is a rotation is straightforward, so the Riemann sphere is in some sense a `natural setting' for this operation. (I should note here that I am fairly new to the subject and am fully aware that I don't have the authority to call things natural.)

---

***Second addendum***: I've received some nice answers (a number of which I've upvoted), but I'm staving off the moment when I accept one as I'm still hoping that somebody may jump in with a picture of a cone slicing the complex plane or something similarly dramatic. I do realize that this is perhaps over optimistic.

Comment: I'm happy to be proven wrong, but offhand am skeptical there's a more satisfying explanation than your half-angle computation. (By comparison, it takes algebraic work to show lines and circles in the plane correspond to circles on the sphere, the geometric fact underpinning the intuition about images of lines under the reciprocal.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: You're definitely right: I _have_ ignored the non-trivial (for me) computation required to establish the correspondence you refer to; I have outlined my reasons for doing so in an edit. As for your scepticism, I'm sorry to hear it: I _was_ worried that there might be no explanation as eminently satisfactory as the Riemann sphere is for inversion, but this is more damning.

Comment: (+1) to the question and existing answers, though both (in my view) amount to the double-angle calculation. Still hoping to see (or find) a clean geometric picture....

Answer (score 28):

Let's identify $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ via the obvious map $x+iy \to (x,y)$. The squaring map is given by $(x,y) \to (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$.  Instead of thinking about the square root map let's just ask: What gets sent to the line $ax+by = c$?

The condition that a point gets send to this line via the squaring map is just $a(x^2-y^2) + 2bxy = c$.  This is a degree 2 polynomial equation so it defines a (possibly degenerate) conic.  Since the coefficients of $x^2$ and $y^2$ have opposite signs the only possibilities are a hyperbola or a pair of lines.

Comment: This feels like a far neater way to solve the problem than my dance with polar coordinates. Viewed in this inverse manner it seems almost as if this map (being only a polynomial) is `too easy' to have something like the Riemann sphere going for it :(

Answer (score 6):

Don't know that square roots can be intuited in terms of inversions (or, more generally, Mobius transforms), but it can be shown that $\,z^2 = 1 + i y \implies \big||z+\sqrt{2}|-|z-\sqrt{2}|\big|=2\,$ which is the geometric definition of the same hyperbola $\,x^2-y^2=1\,$.

This follows from $\,z^2=1+iy \implies z^2+\bar z ^2=2 \implies (z+\bar z)^2=2 + 2 |z|^2\,$. With $\,z\,$ in the right half plane $\,z+\bar z = \sqrt{2(|z|^2+1)}\,$, then:

$$
\begin{align}
\big|z\pm\sqrt{2}\big|^2 &= \big(z\pm\sqrt{2}\big)\big(\bar z \pm \sqrt{2}\big)
\\ &= |z|^2 \pm \sqrt{2}(z+\bar z)+2
\\ &= |z|^2 \pm 2\sqrt{|z|^2+1}+2
\\ &= \left(\sqrt{|z|^2+1}\,\pm\,1\right)^2
\end{align}
$$

Therefore $\require{cancel}\,\big|z+\sqrt{2}\big|-\big|z-\sqrt{2}\big|= \left(\cancel{\sqrt{|z|^2+1}}\,+\,1\right) - \left(\cancel{\sqrt{|z|^2+1}}\,-\,1\right) = 2\,$.

Comment: I should clarify that I'm not really looking for an explanation that uses fractional linear maps. Rather, I only included that example to give an example of a map (inversion) that while strange in the complex plane, can be viewed in another setting where it becomes very natural (I've edited my question to better explain this; it appears that I didn't do a very good job the first time around). However, I do like this since it shows directly (if in a somewhat reverse-engineered fashion) that the curve satisfies the defining property of a hyperbola.

Comment: @xryophile Your question was clear enough from the beginning. I do not have a direct answer to it, however, and I am not sure there is one along those lines. The construction here is not too "*natural*", either, but brings it closer to the geometric interpretation. The derivation was straightforward enough that it's likely possible to translate it into an entirely geometric argument, though I'll have to leave that to someone better versed in conic sections geometry.

Answer (score 6):

If you work out a sketch in polar form, you will get an immediate visual hint of what kind of mapping the square root is giving for lines that do not pass through the origin.
You will notice that, since the argument of the line goes from $- \pi /2 $ to $\pi /2$, the argument of the root shall stay within $(- \pi /4,  \pi /4)$, which are the asymptote lines, shall pass through the point $(x,y)= (r, \theta)=(1,0)$, etc ..

In fact, converting to polar coordinates you have
$$
1 + it = 1 + i\tan \alpha  = \sqrt {1 + \tan ^2 \alpha } \;e^{i\,\alpha }  = \frac{1}
{{\cos \alpha }}\;e^{i\,\alpha } \quad \left| {\; - \frac{\pi }
{2} < \alpha  < \frac{\pi }{2}} \right.
$$
from which
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sqrt {1 + it}  = \frac{1}
{{\sqrt {\cos \alpha } }}\;e^{i\,\alpha /2}  = \frac{1}
{{\sqrt {\cos ^2 \left( {\alpha /2} \right) - \sin ^2 \left( {\alpha /2} \right)} }}\;e^{i\,\alpha /2}  =   \cr 
  &  = \frac{1}
{{\sqrt {\cos ^2 \beta  - \sin ^2 \beta } }}\;e^{i\,\beta }  = \frac{{\cos \beta  + i\sin \beta }}
{{\sqrt {\cos ^2 \beta  - \sin ^2 \beta } }} = \left( {x + iy} \right)  \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad x^2  - y^2  = 1 \cr} 
$$
[image: (1+it)_Polare]

Comment: As it happens this is precisely the heuristic that led me to suspect that the answer might be a hyperbola. However, I don't immediately see how this suggests that it `must' be one.

Comment: @xryophile: added why